# Why do I get an error when filtering by date in a column of the datagridview? 'System.NotSupportedException' DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, datagridview

I get that error along with this

Additional information: Invalid expression: [Invoice Date] = '01 / 11/2020 04:16:02 p.m. '

When filtering by date the other filters that are not date the filters works, this is what I use to put the filters in the datagridview:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                    bs.DataSource = oDsHDRCelMousClic.Tables[0];
                    oDsHDRCelMousClic.BeginInit();
                    grdDET.DataSource = bs;
                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn item in grdDET.Columns)
                    {
                        item.HeaderCell = new DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(item.HeaderCell);

                    }
```

I imagine it is the date format but how do I change it? that brings it from the bd I think, because before the user selects the date of a datetimepicker and there is no time neither am nor pm only the date, that is a problem.

the other is that when you click on the filters some Chinese letters come out or I don't know where

[chinese symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrkcs.png)

and in the first option, if I click on it, a box of more advanced filtering stuff comes out but everything is in Chinese or I don't know what language, the dll will download it from here https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataGridViewAutoFilter/1.0 .0 I imagine that there is the problem

[chinese symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sytk.png)

the third problem is that by clicking on the header of each column to sort the data the first 2 columns on the left side do work well and in the 5 also but in the others if I click it orders them but it does what I have on the CFD button on the right, this is the code when you click on the buttons

```
private void grdDET_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //if (grdDET.Columns["CFD"].DisplayIndex == 8 || grdDET.Columns["Aperak"].DisplayIndex == 9)
    //{

        try
        {
            String Ruta = String.Empty;
            String nombre_xml = String.Empty;
            String strXML = String.Empty;
            String Id_Cnsc_CFD = String.Empty;
            //DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
            String CadenaConexion = String.Empty;

            #region Leemos Archivo de Configuración
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

            XmlNode appSettingsNode =
              xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/userSettings/rutas");

            if (appSettingsNode != null)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node in appSettingsNode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    string value = node.Attributes["value"].Value.ToString();
                    string keyName = node.Attributes["key"].Value.ToString();

                    if (keyName == "RutaArchivo")
                        Ruta = value;
                }

                if (false == Ruta.EndsWith("\\"))
                {
                    Ruta += '\\';
                }

                if (Directory.Exists(Ruta) == false)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No se encontró el directorio \"" + Ruta + "\".");
                }

                foreach (String xmls in Directory.GetFiles(Ruta))
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(xmls);

                    if (fi.Extension.ToUpper() == ".XML")
                    {
                        File.Delete(fi.FullName);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("No se encontró el nodo \"rutas\".");
            }
            #endregion

            //if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            //{
            //    DataGridViewRow row = grdHDR.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            //    grdDET.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            //    //txt3_prov.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            //Id_Cnsc_CFD = e.ColumnIndex.Equals("Id_Cnsc_CFD").ToString().Trim();
            //}

            Id_Cnsc_CFD = grdDET.CurrentRow.Cells["Id_Cnsc_CFD"].Value.ToString().Trim();

            try
            {
                sp = db.GetStoredProcCommand("eDocResumenEmisor_pUP");

                db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pCveOperacion", DbType.String, "X");
                db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pId_Cnsc_CFD", DbType.Int32, Id_Cnsc_CFD);

                oDsDET = db.ExecuteDataSet(sp);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            if (oDsDET.Tables.Count == 1)
            {
                if (oDsDET.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    if (grdDET.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim() == "CFD")
                    {
                        strXML = oDsDET.Tables[0].Rows[0]["XML"].ToString().Trim();
                    }
                    else if (grdDET.CurrentRow.Cells["Aperak"].Value.ToString().Trim() == "Aperak")
                    {
                        strXML = oDsDET.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Aperak"].ToString().Trim();
                    }
                    //if (grdDET.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
                    //{
                    //    int selectedrowindex = grdDET.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                    //    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = grdDET.Rows[selectedrowindex];
                    //    string a = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["CFD"].Value);
                    //}
                    //if (a == "CFD")
                    //{
                    //    strXML = oDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["XML"].ToString().Trim();
                    //}
                    //if (a == "Aperak")
                    //{
                    //    strXML = oDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Aperak"].ToString().Trim();
                    //}
                }
            }

            nombre_xml = System.Guid.NewGuid() + ".XML";

            //Creamos el Archivo APERAK del error...
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(Ruta + nombre_xml, 1024))
            {
                // Add some information to the file.
                byte[] info = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(strXML);
                fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            }

            Process.Start(Ruta + nombre_xml);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    //}

}
```

PD I'm new to windows forms

Comment: Please edit the post with the code that you are using to filter by date.

Comment: there is no filtering code, that is what the dll make I think, the first code I put that makes the filters appear and do the filtering

Comment: or what do you recommend? Do I need the filters to work, any other option?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that I update or change the dll and it no longer shows me the Chinese symbols and keeps sending me the error but now in another class DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell.cs I imagine that this is the code you said @jfiggins

```
 private void UpdateFilter()
    {
        // Continue only if the selection has changed.
        if (dropDownListBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals(selectedFilterValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Store the new selection value. 
        selectedFilterValue = dropDownListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        // Cast the data source to an IBindingListView.
        IBindingListView data = 
            this.DataGridView.DataSource as IBindingListView;

        Debug.Assert(data != null && data.SupportsFiltering,
            "DataSource is not an IBindingListView or does not support filtering");

        // If the user selection is (All), remove any filter currently 
        // in effect for the column. 
        if (selectedFilterValue.Equals("(All)"))
        {
            data.Filter = FilterWithoutCurrentColumn(data.Filter);
            filtered = false;
            currentColumnFilter = String.Empty;
            return;
        }

        // Declare a variable to store the filter string for this column.
        String newColumnFilter = null;

        // Store the column name in a form acceptable to the Filter property, 
        // using a backslash to escape any closing square brackets. 
        String columnProperty = 
            OwningColumn.DataPropertyName.Replace("]", @"\]");

        // Determine the column filter string based on the user selection.
        // For (Blanks) and (NonBlanks), the filter string determines whether
        // the column value is null or an empty string. Otherwise, the filter
        // string determines whether the column value is the selected value. 
        switch (selectedFilterValue)
        {
            case "(Blanks)":
                newColumnFilter = String.Format(
                    "LEN(ISNULL(CONVERT([{0}],'System.String'),''))=0",
                    columnProperty);
                break;
            case "(NonBlanks)":
                newColumnFilter = String.Format(
                    "LEN(ISNULL(CONVERT([{0}],'System.String'),''))>0",
                    columnProperty);
                break;
            default:
                newColumnFilter = String.Format("[{0}]='{1}'",
                    columnProperty,
                    ((String)filters[selectedFilterValue])
                    .Replace("'", "''"));  
                break;
        }

        // Determine the new filter string by removing the previous column 
        // filter string from the BindingSource.Filter value, then appending 
        // the new column filter string, using " AND " as appropriate. 
        String newFilter = FilterWithoutCurrentColumn(data.Filter);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newFilter))
        {
            newFilter += newColumnFilter;
        }
        else
        {
            newFilter += " AND " + newColumnFilter;
        }


        // Set the filter to the new value.
        try
        {
            data.Filter = newFilter;
        }
        catch (InvalidExpressionException ex)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "Invalid expression: " + newFilter, ex);
        }

        // Indicate that the column is currently filtered
        // and store the new column filter for use by subsequent
        // calls to the FilterWithoutCurrentColumn method. 
        filtered = true;
        currentColumnFilter = newColumnFilter;
    }
```

here I get that error now

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFRin.png)

I did not do the sp but bring this:

```
SELECT
```

@Fec_Ini = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @pFec_Ini, 112) + ' 00:00:00')
  ,@Fec_Fin = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @pFec_Fin, 112) + ' 23:59:00')

I tried removing the minutes and seconds of the sp but it didn't work either